# Mac terminal restriction

Tags: api, validation, rest, terminal

I'm building a web API that use a command line on the server.
This command do certain build tasks and it has many optional arguments

I'm not so happy about building a rest API to handle all the arguments and escape/validate all security risk there is...

Is there anyway you could instead whitelist only one command to run by a certain proccess/program or user?

Or can it be as easy as validateing the command if it contains `;` if it dose > consider it as unsafe to run?

Or can you create a little sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a user (login account) on your server that runs your whitelisted command instead of a regular shell when he logs in, if that's what you mean.

For example, I have worked at some sites where there is a user account called "reset" and another called "mountall". So, if you know the password of that account, when you log in, certain databases get reset and you get logged out, or all filesystems in /etc/fstab get mounted and then you get logged out.

Comment: Its more like you forward the command from the website to the server "rather then you login".